Using DuckDB in JetBrains IDE with Jupyter notebook and active auto-suggestions
We have been using very effective workflow that uses JetBrains IDE with Jupyter notebooks. We use AWS Athena and Glue meta-data catalogues to access our data lake.
Usually we capture data-sets via Athena (directly in SQL cell) or using aws-wrangler and then load them into DuckDB for in-memory processing.
What I have been missing is JetBrains IDE integration with DuckDB. JetBrains uses JDBC drivers and DuckDB is supported, but I have not been able to fully incorporate it and have the auto-suggestion working both with Athena data sources and DuckDB.
The problem is that I have not found way to connect to DuckDB instance with JetBrains IDE. JDBC driver does not support hybrid mode that would connect in read-only mode while another instance (Jupyter notebook) manages it in write mode.
Is there any way how to share the database between Jupyter notebook and JetBrains IDE so we can fully use the auto-suggestion features?
